# Google Maps API V3, infoWindow open on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to get something working on the Google Maps API.

What I am trying to achieve is when you click on the html buttons at the bottom they trigger the infoWindow to display. I am a bit unsure where to put the infowindow open function, I have looked at other examples but they didn't seem to work in the code I have got below.

This is what I have got so far:
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jJZK/4/

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);


    // iniitial location + settings
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoom: 16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.376187, -0.525799),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    }


    // locations
    initialize();
    var locations = [
        ['hello', 45.376187, -0.525799],
        ['2', 56.376187, -0.525799],
        ['3', 53.376187, -0.525799],
        ['4', 54.176187, -0.525799],
        ['5', 52.376187, -0.525799]
    ];

    // infowindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    // panTo
    $("#location-menu").on("click", "#location1", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.376187, -0.525799);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#location-menu").on("click", "#location2", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.376187, -0.525799);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#location-menu").on("click", "#location3", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.376187, -0.525799);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#location-menu").on("click", "#location4", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.176187, -0.525799);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });
    $("#location-menu").on("click", "#location5", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.376187, -0.525799);
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
    });

});

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 990px; height: 330px"></div>
<div id="location-menu">
<input type="button" id="location1" value="location 1" />
<input type="button" id="location2" value="location 2"/>
<input type="button" id="location3" value="location 3" />
<input type="button" id="location4" value="location 4"/>
<input type="button" id="location5" value="location 5"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- create a global array ("gmarkers")

> ```
>    var gmarkers = [];
> ```

- push your markers into it

> ```
>    gmarkers.push(marker);
> ```

- use google.maps.event.trigger(, "click") to open the infowindow

  ```
  $("#location-menu").on("click", "#location1", function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[0], "click");
    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.376187, -0.525799);
    map.panTo(laLatLng);
  });
  ```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jJZK/5/)